# Heating Dry Benzenediazonium Chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halides

If we heat BDC with water then phenol is formed. I was wondering what would happen if we heated dry benzenediazonium  chloride. I know that on heating benzenediazonium fluoroborate we obtain fluorobenzene but then it (benzenediazonium  fluoroborate) is insoluble in H2O so there is no confusion over there. On the other hand BDC can be obtained in both forms.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say chloride ion would displace nitrogen giving chlorobenzene.  If this is wrong, inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: I think it just explodes on heating

Comment: please read (this)[http://reag.paperplane.io/00000121.htm] under the heading precautions

Comment: @AdvilSell Thank You. You are right that it will explode. Read it in a few other places as well. However I am surprised that they explode. If you come to know more about , perhaps with more details then please post it up.

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/why-should-the-temperature-be-maintained-at-0-5-c-in-a-diazotisation/76550?r=SearchResults#76550